# Why can't find hardcoded string in the disassembled program?

Tags: disassembly, c

I've wrote a simple program to print something on the screen as below:

```
ebra@him:/tmp/tuts$ cat sample.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    puts("Sample!");
}

ebra@him:/tmp/tuts$ gcc sample.c -o sample
ebra@him:/tmp/tuts$ 
 
ebra@him:/tmp/tuts$ ./sample 
Sample!
```

And then I disassmbled the executable to see what is going on under the hood:

```
ebra@him:/tmp/tuts$ objdump -M intel --disassemble-all sample | grep "<main>:" -A 10
0000000000001149 <main>:
    1149:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    114d:   55                      push   rbp
    114e:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
    1151:   48 8d 3d ac 0e 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0xeac]        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
    1158:   e8 f3 fe ff ff          call   1050 <puts@plt>
    115d:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
    1162:   5d                      pop    rbp
    1163:   c3                      ret    
    1164:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nop    WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
    116b:   00 00 00
```

As you see above, right before calling `puts` function, we have `lea    rdi,[rip+0xeac]`. I assume that `[rip+0xeac]` is the address of the hardcoded text (i.e. "Sample!").

Since `rip` is equal to `0x1151` while exucuting the `mov` line, the value of `[rip + 0xeac]` will be `0x1151 + 0xeac = 0x1ffd`.

But I can't find this address in the disassembled program:

```
ebra@him:/tmp/tuts$ objdump -M intel --disassemble-all sample | grep -i 1ffd
ebra@him:/tmp/tuts$ objdump -M intel --disassemble-all sample | grep -i "Sample!"
ebra@him:/tmp/tuts$
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to search String you cant be  using disassemble-all

```
look at the bytes in both commands if you disassemble how can you find the string

objdump -s sample.exe |grep -i sample
sample.exe:     file format pei-i386
 404040 00000000 53616d70 6c652100 20634000  ....Sample!. c@.

objdump -M intel --disassemble-all sample.exe  --start-address=0x404044 --stop-address=0x40404f

sample.exe:     file format pei-i386


Disassembly of section .rdata:

00404044 <.rdata>:
  404044:       53                      push   ebx
  404045:       61                      popa
  404046:       6d                      ins    DWORD PTR es:[edi],dx
  404047:       70 6c                   jo     4040b5 <.rdata+0x45>
  404049:       65 21 00                and    DWORD PTR gs:[eax],eax

0040404c <_GS_ExceptionPointers>:
  40404c:       20 63 40                and    BYTE PTR [ebx+0x40],ah
```

Comment: Why does `objdump` tries to disassemble the `.rdata` section?! As far as I know, this section contains data/variables only. Am I wrong?

Comment: :\>objdump --help |grep -i "disassemble-all"
  -D, --disassemble-all    Display assembler contents of all sections